# How do I insert a file into a string? (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have been trying to make a program that requires reading from a file and then making the string inside the file part of a string in the program. I have written an example of what I do:

```
gameinfo = [0,0]

def readsave(savefile):
"Reads a file and adds its statistics to variables"
filename = savefile
with open(filename) as file_object:
    gameinfo = file_object.readlines()
print(gameinfo)


readsave('gamesave.txt')

print (gameinfo)
```

But whenever I run this code, all I seem to get is:

```
['thisworks\n', '7']
[0, 0]
```

The `[0,0]` string is what I am trying to change to `['thisworks\n, 7']`, however it only changes inside the function. Is there any way which I can make this change global?

Comment: Just check the file API, maybe there's something you could use?

Comment: What does the text in your file look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is scope, the `gameinfo` variable in the function is a local, not a global. You can declare it global, or pass `gameinfo` around as a parameter. Generally, I avoid global declarations as they can get confusing. I'd recommend passing gameinfo around:

```
def readsave(savefile, gameinfo=[0,0]): # Declare it as a default to the function.
    "Reads a file and adds its statistics to variables"
    with open(savefile) as file_object: # No need to rename this.
        gameinfo = file_object.readlines()
    return gameinfo # Return it so it escapes the scope of this function.


gameinfo = readsave('gamesave.txt') # Save it.

print(gameinfo) # Print it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not shared in functions which means you define `gameinfo = [0,0]` but you are never actually getting that variable in the function.  I you want to save in `gameinfo` you need to use `return` or `global`.  `global` will make it possible to share variables inside the function and outside however this is considered bad practice so don't use it.

To use `return` simply put it in your function.  Always make sure you have only one variable, string, integer returning once per call.

Here is your example rewritten to include the `return` statement I mentioned above:

```
gameinfo = [0,0]

def readsave(savefile):
    "Reads a file and adds its statistics to variables"
    filename = savefile
    with open(filename) as file_object:
        gameinfo = file_object.readlines()
    print(gameinfo)
    return gameinfo


gameinfo = readsave('gamesave.txt')

print (gameinfo)
```

---

You have also made a few other mistakes:

`"Reads a file and adds its statistics to variables"` is not a comment.  Use `"""my text here"""` (triple quotes) or `#my text here` to insert comments.

---

All these things you will learn as you read the Python tutorial.  [Here is one illustrating the use of `return`](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_functions.php).